# como resolver problema en el rollback en un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

estoy intentando crear un procedimiento almacenado en el cual me permita Realizar el registro, si después de realizar el registro existen dos o más gamas con la misma descripción ejecutará el rollback,
en caso contrario, un commit, pero el problema que tengo que no hace lo que le estoy mandando llamar que me haga el rollback me podrian decir que me esta faltando

```
delimiter $$
create procedure TRANS_1 (in gama1 varchar(100),descripcionA text,descripcionN text)
begin
declare tum varchar(100);
start transaction;
insert into GamasProductos(Gama,DescripcionTexto)values(gama1,descripcionN);
select * from GamasProductos where Gama=DescripcionTexto;
set tum=(select Gama from GamasProductos where Gama=descripcionA);
if tum>1 then
rollback;
else
commit;
  END IF;
  select * from GamasProductos;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Esta línea `select Gama from GamasProductos where Gama=descripcionA)` te va a devolver lo que vale `Gama` que no necesariamente pudiera ser un número, ¿no deberías ahí hacer un `COUNT` para que ahora si pueda proceder tu `if`?

Comment: si puede ser como select count(gama)from gamaproductos where descripciontexto=descripcionN?